# How to call "libheif.dll" function from a UWP app

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, pinvoke

I am trying to use ["libheif" library](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif) in my UWP app to decode some HEIC images. 
In the **[heif.h](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif/blob/master/libheif/heif.h)** I added the fallowing **C++ code** `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` to the functions I want to invoke from my C# code:

```
    LIBHEIF_API
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) struct heif_context* heif_context_alloc(void);

    LIBHEIF_API
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void heif_context_free(struct heif_context*);

    LIBHEIF_API
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) struct heif_error heif_context_read_from_file(struct heif_context*, const char* filename,
                                              const struct heif_reading_options*);

    ...
```

Then i compiled the library into a DLL file and added it to my UWP project. In the **C#** code I did this:

```
    namespace Libraries
    {
        public class PInvokeCode
        {
          [DllImport("ms-appx:///libheif.dll")]
          public static extern struct heif_context_alloc();

          [DllImport("ms-appx:///libheif.dll")]
          public static extern void heif_context_free(struct heif_context);

          [DllImport("ms-appx:///libheif.dll")]
          public static extern struct heif_error heif_context_read_from_file(struct heif_context*, const char* filename,
                                              const struct heif_reading_options*);

        }
    }
```

Of course in my UWP i allowed unsafe code nad i set the DLL as content. still, however, i cant seem to get the code to work. It is my first time attempting such thing and I dont know ecactly where i am going wrong!

If you need it, here are the links to [libheif.dll](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1opwSTIMljb3BCimeRnWCVZFjtV5j8Peq/view?usp=sharing) and the [heif.h](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DJO3Z5HGeuJ69Qt_HjZzb9SDboTBpCiw/view?usp=sharing) files..

Comment: _"...i cant seem to get the code to work..."_: you need to expand on this as there is not enough detail about the problems you are having in the question.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with HEIF images, you don't necessarily have to do the decoding yourself. If you have a recent version of Windows and/or have installed he proper WIC codecs, you can load HEIF using WPF's BitmapImage, e.g: `new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\Downloads\surfer_1440x960.heic"))`, same with UWP

Comment: @SimonMourier HEIF containers can have multible images within ( [like this Sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JZc9tRfISDjBCjg3VAQXdH7BqHBqLWTW/view?usp=sharing) ) and i am trying to access those images and the thumbnailes with my code

Comment: @RichardCritten The thing is totorials I have found revolve around simple task (such doing math with int) and not about doing a complex task (pushing a HEIC file to DLL and getting Image sequance in return)
I just get errors like: _DllImport is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'method' declarations._ and _The modifier 'static' and 'extern' is not valid for this item_

Comment: I suggest that create [**Windows Runtime Components**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-cpp) and refer `libheif library` then re-package libheif api. Add the new runtime component to the uwp project.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I want to thank you because I did not know about this tool befor (I am learning code by myself).
I have tried porting [libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif) to a WinRT component using [this guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=vs-2019) , but I get faced with around 190 errors although i can build the project cloned from GitHub. Unless you mean I can do it another way that i don't know of!

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to identify the application is running as a 32-bit or 64-bit
   application.
2. Then ensure libheif.dll (main) could be linked to dependency dlls which are locate at the same directory libde265.dll
   (decoder) and libx265.dll (encoder).
3. Thus download from
   https://github.com/mcychan/libheif/releases if any
   libraries that mentioned above is missing.